# How to create Meteor.js App from barebone sample without "meteor create myApp"?

Tags: meteor

I have a barebone meteor app with nice folder structure:

Like:

```
myApp
   |- .meteor
   |- public
      |- img
   |- client
      |- css
      |- view
      |- js
   |- server
      |- helper
   |- collection
   |- lib
```

I do not want to say :

```
meteor create myNewApp
```

So I copied the myApp -> myNewApp with:

```
cp -rf * /myNewApp/*
```

And then i tried to run the meteor app:

```
cd myNewApp/
meteor run
```

I get:

run: You're not in a Meteor project directory.

To create a new Meteor project:
   meteor create 
For example:
   meteor create myapp

Is there a way to do this?

@**EDIT: I've also tried meteor reset**

```
reset: You're not in a Meteor project directory.

To create a new Meteor project:
   meteor create <project name>
For example:
   meteor create myapp
```

Answer (score 1):

Theres also a hidden directory called `.meteor` that you would need to copy. If you're creating a sort of base structure make sure it has no mongodb database (you can use `meteor reset` to clear it out).

Running `meteor` will create the mongodb database for that instance of your app.

This works on all platforms:

```
meteor create example1
```

Copy the fresh app:

Then make all the edits you want in there

```
mkdir newdirectory
cp -r example1 newdirectory
```

OR

```
mkdir copyofapp
cp -r example1/. copyofapp
```

It will make a copy of it in newdirectory. If you have the convenience of a GUI you can also copy and paste the directory example1 using the normal copy+paste. You can then rename the directory whatever you want for the new app

Using `cp -r` with a wildcard (*) will not copy the hidden files.

Comment: I did copy .meteor - I tested it again, tried running meteor reset. 
Have you actually successfully done this?

Comment: I do this quite often. I don't copy with `cp -rf` (which ignores hidden files) though as I do a simple copy paste of the directory. If you did copy the .meteor also ensure you copy the symlinks. The error `You're not in a meteor project directory` comes from not having a .meteor directory or having errors in it

Comment: Could you put the workflow you use in the answer? I've been at this for 6 hours and still cannot run it.

Comment: Updated. Should work on all *nix platforms also retested it just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

In order to find out which files are needed, simply checkout a Meteor application from GitHub.

Cloning a repository is not much different from copying the file structure.

If you look in the [examples folder for Meteor](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/examples/parties/.meteor) you will see two files packages and release. That's all which is needed.